# Methods to reduce dimensionality within a feature?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-modeling, regression, feature-engineering

Suppose that I am interested in predicting an outcome (say, the arrival delay [in seconds] of a flight) based upon a set of features. 
One of these features is a nominal variable - `carrier` - that specifies the airline carrier of the flight. This feature has 16 different values. After investigation of how arrival delay is distributed across each carrier, it appears that some carriers could be collapsed into one value (e.g., "AS" and "HA" or "WN" and "B6").

```
install.packages("nycflights13")
library(nycflights)

boxplot(
    formula = arr_delay ~ with(flights, reorder(carrier, -arr_delay, median, na.rm = TRUE)),
    data = flights,
    horizontal = TRUE, 
    las = 2,
    plot = TRUE
)
```

[image: Boxplots of Arrival Delay (in seconds) by Carrier.]

In general, are there well-known methods for reducing the dimensionality **within a feature**?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization_of_continuous_features They start from continuous features but you can use some of the ideas in order to further aggregate discrete features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a method that groups up the 16 nominal categorical values. If you conduct the regression problem on a tree-based algorithm, say, rpart, it would give you the various splits that you could consider aggregating them up to reduce the number of categorical values.

For example, the tree based algorithm may suggest a split of carrier IN (AS, HA, VC) vs. NOT IN (AS, HA, VC). This effectively would reduce the number of distinct values to 2. You might want to consider more than 1 split to take into account interactions. Overall, this approach would reduce the number of distinct values in a categorical variable.

Comment: `my_tree <- flights %>% select(carrier, arr_delay) %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% rpart::rpart(formula = arr_delay ~ carrier, data = ., method = "anova")` (the `dplyr` package must be loaded before running this expression)

Answer (score 2):

You could try clustering the data with the `carrier` feature removed, add it back in, and look at the distributions of the `carrier` feature per cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the dimensionality by finding correlations within the known set of possibilities.  Perhaps [Principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) could be of use.  As a programmer I found the article's math and formal analysis quite academic: Take a good idea, create a formal description, and analize it (stet) to death.

But the article has plenty of good references.  If you focus on the intention, there are many good ideas to be found.